# use an array as property in the child root (polymer)

Tags: jquery, arrays, polymer

I have two elements. the first one (host) contain an array in a variable (called renderers), that is used as html property on the child element (by using polymer data binding)

```
<my-datatable id="datatable" datas="https://myawesomeurl.com/datasource.php" target-table="manualTable" renderers={{renderers}}>
```

and in the js:

```
renderers: {
  type: Array,
  reflectToAttribute: true
  }
},

attached: function () {
  this.$.datatable.renderDatatable();
  this.renderers = [
 {
   "render": function( data, type, row ) {
     return data +' ('+ row[3]+')';
   },
   "targets": 0
 }
]
}
```

in the child element, this property is declared

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-datatable',
  properties: {
    datas: {
      type: String
    },
    targetTable: {
      type: String
    },
    renderers: {
      type: Array,
      value: []
    }
  },
renderDatatable: function () {
    console.log(this.targetTable);
    console.log("render ", this.renderers);
    var table = jQuery(Polymer.dom(this).getOwnerRoot().host.$[this.targetTable]).DataTable({
  "colReorder": true,
  "paging":   false,
  "info": false,
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": this.datas,
  "columnDefs": this.renderers,
  dom: 'Blfrtip',
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
  ]
});
```

But in the console log of `this.renderers`, it's always empty. I don't get it. Any clue?
(And in case you are wondering, I'm trying to make a jquery data table element which would take columns renderers as inputs)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`<my-datatable id="datatable" datas="https://myawesomeurl.com/datasource.php" target-table="manualTable" renderers$="{{renderers}}">`

When binding attribute values it should have `$` sign.

See [Polymer Data Binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding)